# How to send var array from html to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

What's the best way of sending a var array from html to php?
I have tried using `serialise` but it doesn't seem to work correctly. 
Thanks

```
//HTML
var arrayTextAreasNames = ['1','2','3'];
xhttp.open("GET", "MyPhpScript.php?hId=" + inputId + "&arrayTextAreasNames=" + serialize(arrayTextAreasNames), true);
//Note: along with the array I am also sending another variable called inputId

//PHP
$arrayTextAreasNames = unserialize($_GET["arrayTextAreasNames"]); 
console.log($arrayTextAreasNames); //The array is not read properly in php (empty!)
```

Comment: How about POST method. Use `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` in PHP instead of `console.log`

Comment: `console.log` not working in php. it is used in javasctipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do two steps in Javascript.

1. stringify object: It must be a string for HTTP GET to server.
2. encode for valid URI: encode for legal URI string.

```js
var arrayTextAreasNames = ['1','2','3'];
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(arrayTextAreasNames);
console.log('before encode, ', jsonstring);

var encoded = encodeURIComponent(jsonstring);
console.log('encoded, ', encoded);

/// xhttp.open("GET", "MyPhpScript.php?hId=" + inputId + "&arrayTextAreasNames=" + encoded, true);
```

In PHP ([Live demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3937a86cf46c221a11ec7169685b5f62d50be59)),
You can then decode back to your expected string.

```
$uri = '%5B%221%22%2C%222%22%2C%223%22%5D';
$result= urldecode($uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's dirty, but maybe something like this:

```
var arrayString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++)
{
    arrayString += "&element" + i + "=" + varArray[i];
}
```

And then you can add the arrayString to you URL

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your array into json using `JSON.stringify`and pass it by using `encodeURIComponent`

```
var arrayTextAreasNames = ['1','2','3'];
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arrayTextAreasNames);

xhttp.open("GET", "MyPhpScript.php?hId=" + inputId + "&arrayTextAreasNames=" + encodeURIComponent(jsonString), true);
```

And in php you decode json ny using `rawurldecode`

```
$arrayTextAreasNames = json_decode(rawurldecode($_GET['arrayTextAreasNames']));
```